# ArcGIS Portal: Webadaptor cannot connect to Portal?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-portal

I'm trying to setup an ArcGIS for Portal 10.2.2 installation on Windows Server 2012, which are both running on a VM (Hyper-V). I have both installed Portal for ArcGIS as well as the Webadaptor and all i need to do is to connect them. The Portal Service is running and the website is accessible under `http://localhost:7080/arcgis/home`. The Web Adaptor is running with tomcat 7 and SSL. I have set up a self-signed SSL certificate. The connector in my server.xml looks like this:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Tomcat 7.0\webadaptor.ks"
           keystorePass="passwort"/>
```

When i open the web interface of the adapter via `http://localhost/arcgis/webadaptor` a dialog shows up where i can choose between ArcGIS Server and Portal. When i choose "Portal" and click on continue i get an error saying that the url of the web adaptor configuration is only accessible from the machine that hosts the web adaptor. I don't understand that because it is the same machine and i'm accessing it via localhost.

Can someone explain me whats wrong, please?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried connecting them without the web adapter? The web adapter is only for cases where you need port 80 or port 443 access (remapped from 6080/6443).  Since you're running everything off localhost, and can evidently set your own port policy, just ensure they're open and you should be ok without the web adapter.

That said, highly suggest you break out AGS and Portal onto two different VMs.  We are managing Portal and AGS (both 10.5) with the web adapter (needs to be installed for both appliances) and this gives much better performance.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the web adaptor is running via SSL, so i have added my tomcat configuration details. I'm quite unexperienced with SSL and port redirecting and this whole area. I guess i need the adapter with that configuration, am i right?

Comment: You don't particularly need the adapter for HTTP/HTTPS.  Both will work without it.  It's just that you'll have to append a :6080 or a :6443 at the end of your URL for portal and server.  This is why I figured, rather than complicate things with the web adapter, try getting everything working without it first.  Then implement it once everything else is working.

Comment: Are you sure? Because on my Portal web page it explicitly says: `In order to access your portal, you need to install the ArcGIS Web Adaptor and configure it for use with Portal for ArcGIS. To get started, see About the ArcGIS Web Adaptor.`

Comment: Hm. There are a few things that aren't necessarily correct on the ArcGIS pages.  For example, I think it also mentions you should install web adapter for *either* portal or server, but not both -  yet we had to install it for both.  My suggestion at this point, if you cannot get it to work without it, is to get in touch with your Esri customer service rep and get direct support that way.  There is a lot they can help you with that is not out on the public documentation (yet).